# Angular CLI 7 installed angular material 9

Tags: angular, typescript

**My pc has installed angular cli version 7.3.10 & ts 3.2.4 
then i have hit below command for installing angular material>**

npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations hammerjs

Now i can see angular material version 9 has installed

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.3",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.3",
```

My problem is when i add material like progress bar then application could not compile and showing below errors:

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/cdk/coercion/array.d.ts(10,60): error TS1005: ',' expected.

node_modules/@angular/cdk/coercion/array.d.ts(10,61): error TS1005: ',' expected.

node_modules/@angular/cdk/coercion/array.d.ts(10,75): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.

node_modules/@angular/cdk/coercion/array.d.ts(10,77): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

Can anyone please help. why angular cli 7 has installed 9 material , i could not understand.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the `@angular/core` is version `~7.2.0` but the `@angular/material` is `^9.2.3`. You either need to upgrade the Angular or downgrade the Angular Material library. I'd rather downgrade the Material library. Try the following commands in order

```sh
npm uninstall @angular/material
npm uninstall @angular/cdk
npm install @angular/material@7.2.0
npm install @angular/cdk@7.2.0
```

Comment: I have installed matereial 7.3.7 and cdk 7.3.7, then app compiled nicely. I have imported mat button this is working but when i import mat progress bar it's saying: odule '"../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar"' has no exported member 'MatProgressBarModule'.

Comment: Not exactly sure. Try to remove `package-lock.json` file and `node modules` directory and run `npm install` again. Also make sure the Material and CDK library are versions `~7.2` in the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happened (normally the dependencies of material 9 are set to angular 9), but you can delete it and resintall the correct version again

```
npm un -S @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm add -S @angular/material@7 @angular/cdk@7
```